# How can I move the docker images directory to a remote server?

Tags: docker, openwhisk

I followed a tutorial to bind the /var/docker/lib directory to my remote server directory. I restarted the docker and containerd service and both worked. However, when I tried to run the hello-world images, it failed and gave very little information.

What should I do to let the docker work again?

Tutorial link: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-private/3.1.1?topic=pyci-specifying-default-docker-storage-directory-by-using-bind-mount

Result:
[docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asZmR.png)

Storage:
[Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmRbX.png)

Comment: Could you please replace the images with the actual response or code as it is more readable?

Comment: This isn't really a programming-related question and might be better asked somewhere else, maybe [sf] or [unix.se].  I'd expect `/var/lib/docker` to _always_ be local, though, you can get some interesting corruption problems if the network hiccups or if multiple Docker daemons access the same files.  I might stop the Docker daemon, `rm -rf /var/lib/docker`, and start over.